# wrapping my head around document oriented databases

Tags: mongodb, couchdb, database

Trying to understand document oriented databases and how to best use them.

Let say you have a blog. First of all is a DOD a reasonable choice for this?

If so, would it be a good idea to break up the stores into months perhaps so that you don't end up with a gigantic document after say ten years?

Comment: It all depends on the features, the # of users, types of queries, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First of all is a DOD a reasonable choice for this?

If you expect to do relational queries on this data, then no. If you will be limited to queries on hierarchical data, then DOD is a good fit.

This sentence here is half opinion, but I think you will find only a few disadvantages and possibly many advantages with a traditional relational SQL database.

> If so, would it be a good idea to break up the stores into months perhaps so that you don't end up with a gigantic document after say ten years?

I've never used CouchDB, but I can speak for MongoDB.

MongoDB has a limit of 16MB for one document, (though there are ways of increasing this limit). But there are no real limits on database size. In fact, MongoDB is very easy to shard, if needed.

Answer (score 2):

The [Definitive Guide to CouchDB](http://guide.couchdb.org/index.html) has a [chapter](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/standalone.html) dedicated to building a blog engine using CouchDB.

Short answer: anything that you can be easily represented with a note card or sheet of paper is well-suited for a document database. Blog posts and comments are good examples of entities that fit this document metaphor pretty well.